Java - How to set a file time before 1970?
With the following code
long newDate = Date.parse("12 Oct 1960 13:25:00");
file.setLastModified(newDate);

I get     java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Negative time
And with this code
public class FileTimes {

  static long getCalendarMillis(int year) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(year, 10-1, 12, 13, 25, 00);
    return  cal.getTimeInMillis();
  }
  static long getDateMillis(int year) {
    return switch (year) {
      case 1960 -> Date.parse("12 Oct 1960 13:25:00");
      case 1980 -> Date.parse("12 Oct 1980 13:25:00");
      default -> (new Date()).getTime();
    };
  }
  static void touch(long millis) throws IOException {
    final File parent = new File("log/FileTimes"), file;
    parent.mkdirs();
    try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file = new File(parent, "FileTime"))) {
      out.close();
      Files.setLastModifiedTime(file.toPath(), FileTime.fromMillis(millis));
      System.out.println("Date of file:                  "+new Date(file.lastModified()));
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
      long millis = getDateMillis(1960);
      System.out.println("Millies from Date:             "+millis);
      touch(millis);
      millis = getCalendarMillis(1960);
      System.out.println("Millies from Calendar:         "+millis);
      touch(millis);
      millis = millis / 1000 * 1000 - 1000;
      System.out.println("Millies from Cal rounded down: "+millis);
      touch(millis);
      Thread.sleep(250);
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
}

I get:
Millies from Date:             -290950500000
Date of file:                  Wed Oct 12 13:25:00 CET 1960
Millies from Calendar:         -290950499926
Date of file:                  Thu Jan 01 01:00:00 CET 1970
Millies from Cal rounded down: -290950500000
Date of file:                  Wed Oct 12 13:25:00 CET 1960

Millies from Date:             -290950500000
Date of file:                  Wed Oct 12 13:25:00 CET 1960
Millies from Calendar:         -290950499532
Date of file:                  Thu Jan 01 01:00:00 CET 1970
Millies from Cal rounded down: -290950500000
Date of file:                  Wed Oct 12 13:25:00 CET 1960

Millies from Date:             -290950500000
Date of file:                  Wed Oct 12 13:25:00 CET 1960
Millies from Calendar:         -290950499230
Date of file:                  Thu Jan 01 01:00:00 CET 1970
Millies from Cal rounded down: -290950500000
Date of file:                  Wed Oct 12 13:25:00 CET 1960

In the end I get unknown date with the Nemo file manager on Linux when using:
Calendar cal ... cal.set(...);.
Note, that the millis are little different on each invocation!
But I get the correct date when using deprecated:
Date.parse(...); or I round down the milliseconds.
To me this looks like a bug in Java. What you think?
Here I'm at CET.

In what time zone should we interpret that date and time?

@BasilBourque Just local time zone.

Here I'm at CEST.

Try FileTime ftime = FileTime.from(Instant.parse("1920-01-01T11:11:11Z"));Files.setAttribute(Path.of("/tmp/s"), "basic:lastModifiedTime", ftime);

goose@t410:/tmp$ stat -c "%y" s gives output: 1920-01-01 11:11:11.000000000 +0000. Behold - a file from the Roaring Twenties

@g00se This worked in Windows 10.  But it won't show up in a detailed listing using File Explorer.  It will show up in the general properties menu but it won't show in the same menu under details.

Ah, the strange ways of Windows...

@g00se "Ah, the strange ways of Windows"  You're being too kind.

@g00se @WJS It turned out, that I actually used Calendar than Date to calculate the timestamp millis.
See my edited code above to see, how that matters. Unfortunately using Date to calculate the millis is deprecated.

Yes, using any of those classes is not recommended at all. They are superseded by java.time

I definitely recommend you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date and time work and FileTime.from(Instant) for converting an Instant from java.time to a FileTime. Don’t use Calendat. Don’t use Date. Even if you insisted on Date, stay away from Date.parse(), deprecated for more than 25 years because it works unreliably.

And I have to say I rather agree with Stephen - should you be doing this at all?

Is it just me? I don’t understand the question. File.setLastModified() clearly documents: Throws: IllegalArgumentException - If the argument is negative. What results had you expected from your snippets?? Also my Ubuntu Linux file manager shows “12 okt 1960” after setting the modified time to that from Java using your code.

Where do you see unknown date in your output? I see it nowhere? It was me downvoting.

@Anonymous unkown date is shown in the graphical file manager, here Nemo.
The use of deprecated Date.parse() was just to simplify the example, in "real world" I used Calendar, which results in the problem. So "used your code" would mean to use Calendar.

So you will have me believe that the result of passing a time before 1970 to Files.setLastModifiedTime() depends, not on which time I pass, but on whether the time comes from Calendar or form Date.parse()? I very seriously doubt it. That would at the very least require a [mre] demonstrating exactly that. Also if your question is Nemo shows “unknown time”, that may not be a programming question and hence not suitable for Stack Overflow. Thakns for trying to explain, but you just managed to increase my confusion. :-(

I guess could be that Nemo cannot display all negative file times that are not on the whole second. It’s obviously nothing I can know. You may make experiments using the hypothesis.

File.lastModified() returns 0 on errors: Returns: A long value representing the time the file was last modified, ..., or 0L if the file does not exist or if an I/O error occurs. ... Why this happens in some of your cases I cannot tell.

I have reproduced using the Files file manager version 42.6 on Ubuntu Linux. I did Files.setLastModifiedTime(path, FileTime.fromMillis(-290950499926L));. After that Files  shows “Modified” as “unknown”. I still suspect the negative file time that is not on a whole second since a time on a whole second works. Might it be a bug somewhere in Linux that causes both the file managers and File.lastModified() in Java to fail to retrieve the time?

Interestingly enough after setting the modified time as above Files.getLastModifiedTime(path) returns 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z. This must be what the documentation means when in mentions “... or an implementation specific default when a time stamp to indicate the time of last modification is not supported by the file system”.

On my Linux (Ubuntu 22), the border seems to go exactly at the fractional seconds before 1970. Setting the time to -1000, 1, 500 and 1000 all work as expected. Setting it to -500 gives the behaviour where I cannot retrieve the same time back.

What also happened in your code was that Calendar polluted your time with milliseconds-of-second that you never asked for. Calendar does that. One of the many reasons to avoid that class. java.time and Instant work. Should you have milliseconds in your Instant that Files cannot process, use yourInstant.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS). Finally use FileTime.from(yourTruncatedInstant).

@Anonymous All your thinking I've done before. My file manager interprets a file time of 0L as invalid an therefore "unknown". This fact – I thought – is obvious from my output listing, and doesn't need to be discussed. The real problem is, that Files.setLastModifiedTime() doesn't process file times correctly if nanos != 0, regardless if the timestamp comes from Date, Calendar, LocalDateTime or Instant.
An additional problem is, that the calculation from Calendar is "fuzzy". The reason may be that it tries to respect the "leap seconds", which accumulate over the decades.

@Anonymous The JavaDoc of File.setLastModified() states: "Parameters: time - The new last-modified time, measured in milliseconds since the epoch (00:00:00 GMT, January 1, 1970) " There is nothing said about a restriction on times after Jan 1 1970. This is a documentation bug. But you are right, that the restriction is mentioned indirectly by the "Throws:" section.

Another bug is, that in case of negative input File.setLastModified() sets the file time to 0L instead of leaving it untouched.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@Anonymous Just truncating to seconds does not really solve the problem. in case of -290950499926L from Calendar it will produce a time of 13:24:59 instead 13:25:00. The better calculation is shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78430589/5399598

@Anonymous Unfortunately the discussion above has been closed. Finally after long time of waiting I was able to report the bug. The URL is: http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=JDK-8335398
Currently it's not yet reachable, but after some days it should be.

Irrespective of how timestamps before the UNIX epoch are represented, how does it make sense for a file to be last modified >before< 1970?  UNIX / Linux didn't exist then, so neither could a file.  The timestamps are for the file, not for the information that the file represents; e.g. its contents.
What you are trying to represent here would be better represented some other way; i.e. not by hijacking file system timestamps for a purpose they weren't intended for.
When external tools on some systems (ls, the Linux file manager) behave strangely with pre-epoch file timestamps, it is probably because the designers of said tools are treating those timestamps as bad data.  There's probably nothing you can do about that.

As noted, Java can handle timestamps before the epoch.  If you are using "seconds since the epoch" representation, just use a negative integer.
You tried using File.setLastModified.  That fails because the method has a hardwired check for negative timestamps. (Per the OpenJDK Java 11 source code.)
In your updated question, you claim that this documented behavior is a bug in Java.  Well, maybe if you had reported it in 1997 against Java 1.0 it would have been possible to fix it.  However, java.io.File is a legacy class that is full of inconsistent and/or undocumented behavior that can't be fixed without breaking "millions" of existing Java applications written in the last nearly 30 years.  If you want consistent, well documented behavior, use Path and Files.  These and other NIO classes were added in Java 7 in 2011 to (among other things) help Java to "play nicely" with various OS dependent file system features.
You should be using Files.setLastModifiedTime instead. Its javadoc says this.

public static Path setLastModifiedTime(Path path,
                                       FileTime time)
                                throws IOException

Updates a file's last modified time attribute. The file time is
converted to the epoch and precision supported by the file system.
Converting from finer to coarser granularities result in precision
loss. The behavior of this method when attempting to set the last
modified time when it is not supported by the file system or is
outside the range supported by the underlying file store is not
defined. It may or not fail by throwing an IOException.

The implication is that if the file system support timestamps prior to the UNIX epoch, then setLastModifiedTime should work.
Looking (again) at the OpenJDK Java 11 source code for the UNIX / Linux case, it will attempt to set the modified time that you gave.  If the syscall to set the timestamp(s) fails with an EINVAL, and the timestamp was negative, it will try again setting the timestamp to zero instead.  (Note that this behavior is not documented, so it could conceivably change between Java versions.)

I have a bunch of photos from the sixties and before, scanned from slides. To me it makes sense to see the original dates directly in the file manager.
But besides, it turned out, that Files.setLastModifiedTime() sets the file time to Jan 1 1970 when calculating the millis with the recommended class Calendar. See my edited code above.

From your perspective, maybe it makes sense.  From the perspective of OS tools it doesn't.  For example, if you use incremental file system backup / restore software, setting your file modification timestamps to values that don't match the last modifications of the files on disk will typically result in them not getting backed up.  Bad idea.  If you want to record this kind of metadata, it is better to use extended attributes, a database or something else.

Also .... don't use Calendar.  It is a legacy class, since Java 7 was released.  Use java.time classes instead.  Like-wise, java.util.Date, java.io.File and so on are legacy.

tl;dr
Calculate the number of milliseconds preceding 1970.
long epochMilli =
        LocalDateTime.parse(
                        "12 Oct 1960 13:25:00" ,
                        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "d MMM uuuu HH:mm:ss" ).withLocale( Locale.US )
                )
                .atZone(
                        ZoneId.of( "Europe/Amsterdam" )
                )
                .toInstant( )
                .toEpochMilli( );

java.time
Others address the file system issue. I will address your time calculations.
You are using terribly flawed date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern java.time classes defined in JSR 310.
LocalDateTime
Parse your date-with-time string as a LocalDateTime. Define a formatting pattern to match your incoming string. You must specify a Locale to parse the name of the month.
String input = "12 Oct 1960 13:25:00";
Locale locale = Locale.US;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "d MMM uuuu HH:mm:ss" ).withLocale( locale );
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input , f );

ISO 8601
By the way, I suggest you educate the publisher of your input data about the ISO 8601 standard formats for exchanging date-time values as text. Your input in standard format would be 1960-10-12T13:25. The java.time classes use ISO 8601 formats by default when generating & parsing text — so no need to define any formatting pattern for standard inputs.
ZonedDateTime
You said:

Here I'm at CEST.

So I am guessing that means you want to interpret that input of 1:25 PM on that date as seen from that time zone.
Real time zones
Unfortunately, CEST is not a real time zone. Such pseudo-zones are used for localized display to the user, but are not apprpropiate for programming logic. Those 2-4 character pseudo-zones are not standardized, and are not even unique! A pseudo-zone such as CEST covers many real time zones, each with their own rules. Saying “my time zone is CEST” is like saying “this money is dollars” — US dollars, Canadian dollars, Australian dollars, Bahamian dollars, Guyanese dollar, who knows?
Instead, specify a real time zone in format of Continent/Region. Perhaps you really intended a time zone such as Europe/Amsterdam.
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Amsterdam" ) ;

Apply that time zone to our LocalDateTime to determine a moment, a specific point on the timeline, in a ZonedDateTime object.
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( z ) ;


zdt.toString() = 1960-10-12T13:25+01:00[Europe/Amsterdam]

Instant
Adjust to view that same moment through the wall-clock/calendar of UTC (an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds from the temporal meridian of UTC). We can most easily do that by extracting an Instant. An Instant object is always in UTC, by definition.
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;


instant.toString() = 1960-10-12T12:25:00Z

Milliseconds since epoch
Apparently your file system API expects a count of milliseconds since the epoch reference of first moment of 1970 in UTC, 1970-01-01T00:00Z. That moment is define in the constant Instant.EPOCH.
long epochMilli = instant.toEpochMilli() ;


epochMilli = -290950500000

Notice how negative numbers represent a moment before 1970 UTC.

I have no idea if a value of -290950500000L will work with in your Linux file system.

If you have e.g. Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond(-290950500L, 12340000L); you will still run into the bug with Files.setLastModifiedTime(file.toPath(), FileTime.fromMillis(instant.toEpochMilli()));

Here is a workaround to get a working FileTime from a given Date, Calendar or Instant object from foreign code:
long millis = date.getTime();
// or:
long millis = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
// or:
long millis = instant.toEpochMilli();

// round down *absolutely* – for positive and negative values – to seconds:
millis = Math.floorDiv(millis, 1000) * 1000;

Files.setLastModifiedTime(file.toPath(), FileTime.fromMillis(millis));


I believe this is impossible since the UNIX timestamps that are used by the filesystem are expressed in the amount of seconds since 1970 (actually milliseconds with most Linux filesystems like EXT).
This means that a filetime lower than 1970 would actually wrap around and become a year into the future of which the year depends on the integer size the filestamp is stored in the filesystem. If the UNIX timestamp is stored in 32 bits, 1970 - 1 would be the year 2038. If it is 64 bits it would underflow to a much larger year.
It might be possible to silcence Java by making it a signed integer to make sure the value isn't negative but is automatically underflowed before being passed to the setLastModified function. This way if you try to set the file time to 1969 the file will end up having its actual filetime set to 2038 due to the integer underflowing into the 32 bit integer limit.

The JavaDoc for public static FileTime fromMillis(long value) says: value - the value, in milliseconds, since the epoch (1970-01-01T00:00:00Z); can be negative, so a negative value, i.e. before 1970, should be valid.

According to Wikipedia: “Unix time is typically encoded as a signed integer.” So moments before 1970 can be represented as negative numbers. Integer wraparound and overflow should not be an issue here.
